# method overriding without virtual and override returns only base class method

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, overriding

I just have one basic question :

in below code returns only derived class methods but i don't know why . kindly help to find out the problem.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            A value = new B();
            value.method();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    class A
    {
        public void method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A");
        }
    }
    class B : A
    {
        public void method()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don´t explicitely add any modifier (like `virtual` or `override`) a `new` is implictely added into the code, which yields to the following:

```
class B : A
{
    public new void method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}
```

This **hides** the base-implemenation, but **only** if your reference is of type `B`. In your case you have a reference of the base-type `A`, which has no clue on the `new` member and thus will allways perform a call to the base-class member

I don´t know why you don´t have `virtual` and `override` here. If it´s really not possible for you to add them, you need a reference of the derived type:

```
B value = new B();
value.method();
```

Comment: I think he is asking "why", instead of "how to get it done". Though he create an "new B();" but method from "A class" is called. again why ?

Comment: @KumaranRajK I repeat myself: "This hides the base-implemenation, but only if your reference is of type B". Doesn´t this explain the why-part?